# regex japanese words cannot escape

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding, preg-replace, cjk

I would like to remove some hashtag including japanese and I encounter a problem that some words are not able to be removed.

```
$text = "#食への好きな人と繋かりたい #食への好きな人と繋がりたい #食べるの好きな人と繋がりたい";

echo "\n".$text;
echo "\n".preg_replace("/#([.\w]+)/u", "", $text);
```

the output of above code is:

```
 ゙りたい2 ゙るの好きな人と繋がりたい3
```

whereas the expected output should be empty.

my observation is that if the char contains " on the top right (i.e. `が` or `べ`) this kind of pattern then the words cannot be escape. And if I change it to `か` and `へ` then the words are escaped.

I have spent a while to figure out it but they didn't work. Please help to escape the japanese words. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following regex for a hashtag:

```
#\S+
```

This will match a leading `#` character, followed by one or more non whitespace characters (which would include Japanese Kanji).

Sample script:

```
$text = "#食への好きな人と繋かりたい #食への好きな人と繋がりたい #食べるの好きな人と繋がりたい";
echo $text . "\n";
$text = preg_replace("/#\S+/", "", $text);
echo $text;
```

The second `echo` prints just two spaces (which were separating the three hashtags in the original input);

Comment: The more exact answer, if you really wanted to target only Japanese hashtags, would require writing a regex just for that.  My answer will target _all_ hashtags, regardless of language.

Comment: no problem, I get what you mean and the answer is what I want. I would like to target all hashtags. thanks!